# initializer_list with auto contains multiple expressions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, auto

Rather simple question,

```
auto x11 {1,2,3,4};
auto x1 = {1,2,3,4};
auto x22 {1.0, 2.25, 3.5};
auto x2 = {1.0, 2.25, 3.5};
```

As far as I understand, there should be no difference here with respect to having `=` or not. However, using llvm/clang 6.0.0 (with --std=c++17), I get :

```
main1.cpp:35:17: error: initializer for variable 'x11' with type 'auto' contains multiple
  expressions
auto x11 {1,2,3,4};
~~~~~~~~    ^

main1.cpp:37:20: error: initializer for variable 'x22' with type 'auto' contains multiple
  expressions
auto x22 {1.0, 2.25, 3.5};
```

From Stroustroup's C++ book, page.162:

```
auto x1 {1,2,3,4}; // x1 is an initializer_list<int>
auto x2 {1.0, 2.25, 3.5 }; // x2 is an initializer_list of<double>
```

So, is there really a problem in not having **=** in there?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the `=` you have for `x1` and `x2` is ***not*** the assignment operator, it's for *initialization*. More specifically with the `=` you have [*copy-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization), and without you have [*direct-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#direct-list-initialization).

Comment: i just did not make it clear and made it more confusing -> i did not mean <assignment operator> per se, i meant that i thought the '=' symbol in there will make 0 difference on the choice of initialization, which is not the case as it has been elaborated already... will edit that

Comment: This was mentioned by Scott Meyers in his talks as well =>  [TypeDeductionandWhyYouCare](https://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf) : Slide 20

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rule of [auto type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#auto_type_deduction) changed since [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html). (This is considered as a defect in C++14).

> In direct-list-initialization (but not in copy-list-initalization),
> when deducing the meaning of the auto from a braced-init-list, the
> braced-init-list must contain only one element, and the type of auto
> will be the type of that element:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = {3}; // x1 is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2{1, 2}; // error: not a single element
> auto x3{3};    // x3 is int
>                // (before N3922 x2 and x3 were both std::initializer_list<int>)
> ```

So before N3922, all the variables in your sample work fine and have type `std::initializer_list<int>`. But since N3922, for direct initialization (i.e. for `x11` and `x22`) the braced-initializer must contain only one element (and their type would be the type of the element), then the code become ill-formed.

See [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) and [N3681](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) for more.

Comment: Do you know the reasoning behind this change in standard? It might break existing code, so I suppose there should be a good one...

Comment: @Aconcagua: I think the reason was that `auto obviouslyInt {1};` turned out not to be an `int` after all, and this was confusing/annoying to many people.  Having the type of `{...}` depend on the number of expression was likely to be even *more* confusing - so they just forbade it.  There probably isn't *that* much code using uniform initialization yet, and the fix is straightforward (change to copy-list-initialization).

Comment: @Aconcagua I think the reason was to promote both "Use auto" rule and "Use braces" rule. With no modification in the standard `int x=5` would be changed to `auto x{5}` And this was declaring an initializer_list. So to preserve expressivity they needed to find a way to allow deducing an int or an initializer_list. If I remember correctly. Herb Sutter talks about this in his [Back to the Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64) talk during cppcon 2014.

Comment: @Aconcagua, For reference, http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html

Comment: @Aconcagua I'm not sure (that's why I deleted my comment), but I think the reason comes from the inconsistence between braced-initializer and other initializer. e.g. `auto x1 = 42; // int`, `auto x2(42); // int` and `auto x4{ 42 }; // std::initializer_list<int> before C++17`.

Comment: Quite a good argument. The proposition cited would have been even more consequent (in respect to `=` being used). Unfortunately, standard committee did not follow completely. I am very fond of `auto` myself, if used *appropriately*, but all this discussion here clearly shows that it is *not* the Holy Grail *at all* and there sure are situations where better not used. This here is one of these; `int x = 5;` is just so much clearer (worse: `long x = 5;` vs. `auto x{5L};` where it is so easy to either forget or overlook the type suffix - whereas there's no problem with in first expression...).

Comment: Just to add: In this respect, I consider `long x = 7;` and `long x(7);` equivalent (admitted, even the uniform variant of the latter, but I strongly oppose uniform initialisation and thus won't ever write it not even in comments...).

Comment: By the way; This *additionally* is feeding my arguments list against uniform initialisation as well: Without, all this discussion would be entirely obsolete as braces would just simply *always* deduce to an initialiser list (apart from pre-C++11 aggregate initialisation!).

Comment: @Aconcagua:  [N3922 says the rules for auto are too simple](https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU?t=1868). Or, worded differently, it was easier to fix the standard than to fix MSVC.